# Is there any way to play sopcast stream on Android?

Tags: java, android

I would like to have ability to play sopcast channel in my android app, but I can't find any document about it protocol. Is there any lib, doc for doing that?

Thank you all.

Comment: "play sopcast channel" - is it something like live streaming ?

Comment: yes, it's P2P live stream